# cannot update vue data inside function while fetching?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to **VueJs**. This is **laravel 6.0**, I don't know much about variable scopes in javascript but I guess I am missing something in here.

When I write `"self.msg='hello world'"` outside the fetch it works fine.

issue is here:
Even after setting "self.msg = 'hello world'" inside .then() it does not get reflected inside view. means the 'msg' variable is not getting updated.

```
<div class="main" >
    <div class="test"> {{ msg }} </div>
    <!-- output:test  -->
</div>
```

```
export default {
    name:"word-list",
    data() { 
        return {
            msg: 'test'
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchWords();
    },
    methods: {

        fetchWords() {

            let self = this;
            console.log(self.msg);//output: test
            fetch("getAllWords")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then( res => {
                console.log(self.msg);//output: test
                self.msg = "hello world"
                console.log(self.msg);//output: hello world
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error) );
            console.log(self.msg);//output: test
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question here? If you're asking why the value of `self.msg` is `'test'` at the end then that is because `fetch` is asynchronous, so that line runs before the `then` callbacks. Once all the callbacks have finished `self.msg` should be `'hello world'`, which should trigger the template to re-run to reflect the new value.

Comment: yes, but at the end new value supposed to reflect in view template. BTW thanks for reply.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to make it explicit precisely what the problem is? It is still really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: inside created() write this.msg = 'it works' and see if the view update or not ?

Comment: @FidaHasan yes, it gets updated properly if i write it inside created() or  outside fetch call(in fetchWords() method).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here (likely) is due to the fact that you are calling the `fetchWords()` function before the component renders, but not telling it to re-render after the data is retrieved. By that point in time, Vue has no idea that you were triggering a "redraw". You have two options:

1. You can use the `mounted()` ([Vue Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)) lifecycle hook and then your data will be requested as soon as Vue.js mounts the component and then it will know to reset that data point.
2. You can call the `this.nextTick()` function ([nextTick() reading](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)) to force Vue.js to "redraw" the UI.

This is all still a guess, but that's what I have seen thus far when dealing with HTTP and the Vue.js lifecycle hooks.